# grep -r is not working in HP-UX. Is there any alternative commad to be used instead of grep -r in HP-UX?

Tags: grep, hp-ux

I Want to grep recursively in HP-UX.

`grep -r` is not working in HP-UX (the option is not supported). Is there any alternative command to be used instead of grep -r in HP-UX?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Please [edit the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/313400/edit) to show the command you ran, the results you expected to find, and any error messages you got instead.

Comment: 238$ grep -r bill_payment * | more
grep: illegal option -- r
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] pattern [file...]

Comment: I want to search for bill_payment word in any file inside the current directory and subdirectories.

Answer (score 3):

Yes `-r` is a GNU `grep` extension to make it do the work of `find` in addition to the work of `grep`.

Use `find` to find files and `grep` to print lines matching a regular expression in them:

```
find . -type f -exec grep regexp /dev/null {} +
```

(the `/dev/null` is so that the paths of the files are always printed even if only one file name is passed to `grep`).